# Fill Html Selection "Color" by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, colors

I want to fill my color selection by `Script`. When I want to fill my color menu I use this code:

```
    function FillFontColorMenu() {
        FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "fontColorMenu"); // Color of the Font
    }

    function FillBackgroundColorMenu() {
        FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "backgroundColorMenu"); // Background Color
    }

    function GetPossibleColors() { // Create an Array of Colors
        var possibleColors = [];

        possibleColors.push(0x333333);  // Add Color x
        possibleColors.push(0x666666);
        possibleColors.push(0x999999);

        return possibleColors; // Return the Colors
    }

    function FillSelection(possibleValues, elementId) { // Fill the Selection with the Colors
        for(var i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++) {
            var optionElement = "<option value='" + possibleValues[i] + "'>" + possibleValues[i] + "</option>"; // Pass in the Colors
            $('#'+elementId).append(optionElement);
        }
    }
```

How can I store the colors to the `Array`? Do I have to store the values to `RGB` codes? Can I use this color `Array` and pass the colors in the "FillingMethod"? Is there a way to do this or is my idea crap and will never work?

I tried to create a JsFiddle that shows my problem:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13gohndt/)

Comment: Are you going to push specific static colors? or you are looking for dynamic color generation?

Comment: Also a working demo would be appreciated.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: you could store either hex color code or rgb color code.

Comment: When i write possibleColors.push(0x999999); the option element does not show "red" for example, just a big number

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the colors in the `Array` as [hexadecimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and `JavaScript` treats all numbers [as double-precision float point numbers](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html). When you insert the color in the `option` as a text you need to convert the number to `String`. I recommend you to use the `toString` method of the `Number` object, sending `16` as the base number to get a hexadecimal representation of the number:

```js
FillFontColorMenu();
FillBackgroundColorMenu();

function FillFontColorMenu () {
    FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "fontColorMenu");
}

function FillBackgroundColorMenu () {
    FillSelection(GetPossibleColors(), "backgroundColorMenu");
}

function GetPossibleColors () {
    var possibleColors = [];

    possibleColors.push(0x333333); // TEST
    possibleColors.push(0x666666); // TEST
    possibleColors.push(0x999999); // TEST

    return possibleColors;
}

function FillSelection (possibleValues, elementId) {
    for(var i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++) {
        var optionElement = "<option value='" + possibleValues[i] + "'>#" + possibleValues[i].toString(16) + "</option>";
        $('#'+elementId).append(optionElement);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fontColorMenu"></select>
<select id="backgroundColorMenu"></select>
```